Supercharge of supersymmetry transformations of the super-world-sheet coordinates
In the book "String theory and M-theory", the authors mentions on page 114 that "the generators of supersymmetry transformations of the super-world-sheet coordinates, called supercharges, are $$Q_A =\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{\theta}^A}-(\rho^{\alpha}\theta)_A\partial_{\alpha}.$$ How does the author get it? The action is $$S=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int d^2\sigma (\partial_{\alpha}X_{\mu}\partial^{\alpha}X^{\mu}+\bar{\psi}^{\mu}\rho^{\alpha}\partial_{\alpha}\psi_{\mu})$$ and the superfield is $$Y^{\mu}(\sigma^{\alpha},\theta)=X^{\mu}(\sigma^{\alpha})+\bar{\theta}\psi^{\mu}(\sigma^{\alpha})+\frac{1}{2}\bar{\theta}\theta B^{\mu}(\sigma^{\alpha})$$ where the super-world-sheet coordinates are given by $(\sigma^{\alpha},\theta_A)$. Shoud we tranform the action by replacing $X^{\mu}$ to $Y^{\mu}$ and calculate the supercurrent and then the supercharge? or is there another way?
My try: Operating on Y with $Q$, we have $$Q_A Y^{\mu}(\sigma^{\alpha},\theta)=\psi^{\mu}(\sigma^{\alpha})+\theta B^{\mu}(\sigma^{\alpha})-(\rho^{\alpha}\theta)\partial_{\alpha}X^{\mu}(\sigma^{\alpha})-(\rho^{\alpha}\theta)\bar{\theta}\partial_{\alpha}\psi^{\mu}(\sigma^{\alpha}).$$

Operate on Y with Q, and compare to Y. What do you find?

Compare to a rotation of a vector and a bilinear scalar action thereof.

@CosmasZachos Thank you for the comments. I've added expression $YQ$ in my answer. How to compare it with $Y$?

@CosmasZachos sorry, I don't understand. Could you please explain a little bit more?

Basic super field manipulations should be detailed in your text. Otherwise, you should be reading something friendlier, like P West's book.

Dear @CosmasZachos Thank you very much for the suggestion. I didn't know much about super field manipulations. Appreciate your help.

Hint: up to suitable Grassmann  signs, etc, & Fierzing,  you have, from the above, something like
$$\delta Y^\mu= \delta X^\mu   +\bar{\theta}\delta \psi^{\mu}+\frac{1}{2}\bar{\theta}\theta ~\delta B^{\mu} ,$$
so  that
$$
\delta X^\mu = \bar \epsilon \psi^\mu ,\\
\delta \psi^\mu = \partial \!\!/ X^\mu \epsilon+ B^\mu \epsilon ,\\
\delta B^\mu = \bar \epsilon \partial \!\!/ \psi^\mu ,
$$
but, on shell ($B^\mu=0$), the middle increment simplifies to a standard susy transformation. Inserting these increments into Noether's construction on S, you find the supercurrent/supercharge you'd expect.
This is the superspace analog of a 2d rotation of
$$
\vec V= v_x \hat x + v_y \hat y \\
\vec V \cdot \vec V= v_x^2+ v_y^2
$$
by an infinitesimal angle ε,
$$
\delta \vec V= v_x ( ε \hat y)  + v_y (-ε \hat x)
= (-ε v_y)\hat x + ( ε v_x)\hat y  \qquad  \leadsto \\
\delta v_x= -ε v_y , \qquad  \delta v_y=  ε v_x .
$$
