About series expansion of the superfield
The super-world-sheet coordinates are given by $(\sigma^{\alpha},\theta_A)$, where $\theta_A$ is a Majorana spinor. One can then introduce a superfield $Y^{\mu}(\sigma^{\alpha},\theta)$. Why $Y^{\mu}$ has a series expansion in $\theta$ of the following form? $$Y^{\mu}(\sigma^{\alpha},\theta)=X^{\mu}(\sigma^{\alpha})+\bar{\theta}\psi^{\mu}(\sigma^{\alpha})+\frac{1}{2}\bar{\theta}\theta B^{\mu}(\sigma^{\alpha}).\tag{4.19}$$ If we expand the $Y^{\mu}$ in $\theta$ we have $$Y^{\mu}(\sigma^{\alpha},\theta)=Y^{\mu}(\sigma^{\alpha},0)+\theta (Y^{\mu})'(\sigma^{\alpha},0)+\frac{1}{2}\theta^2 (Y^{\mu})''(\sigma^{\alpha},0)+\cdots .$$ Why $(Y^{\mu})'(\sigma^{\alpha},0)$ and $(Y^{\mu})''(\sigma^{\alpha},0)$ must be the bosonic and fermionic fields $X^{\mu}$ and $\psi^{\mu}$, respectively?
Reference: "String theory and M-theory" by Becker-Becker-Schwarz on page 113.

$\theta$ and $\overline{\theta}$ are Grassmann-odd-valued variables, so $\theta^{n}=0$ for $n>1$ (and the same for $\overline{\theta}$.

Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/835716/2451
