How to get $[\bar{\epsilon}^CQ^C,\theta^A]=\epsilon ^A$?
The generators of supersymmetry transformations of the super-world-sheet coordinates $(\sigma^{\alpha},\theta_A )$ are $$Q_A=\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{\theta}^A}-(\rho^{\alpha}\theta)_A\partial_{\alpha}.$$
In order to prove $[\bar{\epsilon}Q,\theta^A]=\epsilon^A$, I face with this term $\theta^A\bar{\epsilon}Q$. What should we do about this term? The other term $\bar{\epsilon}Q\theta^A$ is exactly $\epsilon^A$.
My try: We have $$[\bar{\epsilon}Q,\theta^A]=\bar{\epsilon}Q\theta^A-\theta^A\bar{\epsilon}Q.$$ For the term $\bar{\epsilon}Q\theta^A$ we have: $$\bar{\epsilon}Q\theta^A=Q\bar{\epsilon}\theta^A=Q\bar{\theta}^A\bar{\epsilon}=\big(\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{\theta}^A}-(\rho^{\alpha}\theta)_A\partial_{\alpha}\big)\bar{\theta}^A\bar{\epsilon}$$ $$\frac{\partial\bar{\theta}^A}{\partial\bar{\theta}^A}\bar{\epsilon}=\bar{\epsilon}.$$ But for the other term, I don't know what to do: $$\theta^A\bar{\epsilon} Q?$$ $Q$ acts on what?
Every test function $Y^{\mu}(\sigma^{\alpha},\theta )$ is expressed as $X^{\mu}(\sigma^{\alpha})+\bar{\theta}\psi^{\mu}(\sigma^{\alpha})+\frac{1}{2}\bar{\theta}\theta B^{\mu}(\sigma^{\alpha})$. We have $$\theta^A\bar{\epsilon} QY^{\mu}=\theta^A\bar{\epsilon}\Big( \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{\theta}^A}-(\rho^{\alpha}\theta)_A\partial_{\alpha}\Big) \Big( X^{\mu}(\sigma^{\alpha})+\bar{\theta}\psi^{\mu}(\sigma^{\alpha})+\frac{1}{2}\bar{\theta}\theta B^{\mu}(\sigma^{\alpha})\Big)$$ $$=\theta^A\bar{\epsilon}\Big( \psi^{\mu}+\theta B^{\mu} -(\rho^{\alpha}\theta)_A\partial_{\alpha}X^{\mu}-(\rho^{\alpha}\theta)_A\bar{\theta}^{A}\partial_{\alpha}\psi^{\mu}-\frac{1}{2}(\rho^{\alpha}\theta)_A \bar{\theta}\theta \partial_{\alpha}B^{\mu}\Big).$$ Since $\theta^2=0$, so we get $$\theta^A\bar{\epsilon} QY^{\mu}=\theta^A\bar{\epsilon} \psi^{\mu}.$$ But this is not zero.

Could you show in more detail what you tried?

@Ruffolo I've added my try.

When we consider differential operators, it is supposed that they "act" on something, as you asked in the final. So we actually should evaluate $[\bar\epsilon Q,\theta^A] f$ for some test function $f(\theta,\alpha)$

@Ruffolo I understood but how can I show the term $\theta^A \bar{\epsilon}Q$ is zero?

Every test function $Y^{\mu}(\sigma^{\alpha},\theta )$ is expressed as $X^{\mu}(\sigma^{\alpha})+\bar{\theta}\psi^{\mu}(\sigma^{\alpha})+\frac{1}{2}\bar{\theta}\theta B^{\mu}(\sigma^{\alpha})$.

Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/835716/2451

@Ruffolo I've added my another try.

Do not skip the free spinor index of $\bar \epsilon _B$, and utilize the Fierz identity of your text.

@CosmasZachos The only Fierz identity in my text is $\theta_A \bar{\theta}B =-\frac{1}{2}\delta{AB}\bar{\theta}_C \theta_C$. Could you please tell me how to prove $\theta^A \bar{\epsilon}\psi^{\mu}$ is zero?

TL;DR You might be barking up the wrong tree, as your term you target to vanish simply doesn't... I edited your title to be more meaningful and practical. Recall, even in ordinary space, $[\partial_x, x]=1$.
